# With contextIsolation = true, is it possible to use ipcRenderer?

Tags: security, electron

Here's my setup:

Step 1. Create a preload.js file with the code:

```
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

Step 2. Preload this file in your main.js via webPreferences:

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    }
  });
```

Step 3. In a renderer:

```
console.log(window.ipcRenderer); // Works!
```

Now following Electron's security guide, I wish to turn `contextIsolation=true`: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content

Step 2bis.

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    }
  });
```

Step 3bis. In a renderer:

`console.log(window.ipcRenderer); // undefined`

Question: can I use [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) when `contextIsolation=true`?

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you are still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 31):

## 2022 edit

For those that would like additional context of understanding the IPC renderer, I've published a [post](https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/) that explains this concept, as well as related security concerns that revolve around using the IPC renderer.

## new answer

You can follow the setup [outlined here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738). This setup is being used in [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) Essentially, this is what you can do:

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
    }
  });

  // Load app
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));

  // rest of code..
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
  fs.readFile("path/to/file", (error, data) => {
    // Do something with file contents

    // Send result back to renderer process
    win.webContents.send("fromMain", responseObj);
  });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
            console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
        });
        window.api.send("toMain", "some data");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## original

You are *still* able to use ipcRenderer in a renderer process with contextIsolation set to true. The [contextBridge](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge) is what you want to use, although there is a [current bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21437) that is preventing from you calling ipcRenderer.on in a renderer process; all you can do is send from the renderer process to the main process.

This code is taken from [secure-electron-template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) a template for Electron built with security in mind. (I am the author)

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "electron",
    {
        ipcRenderer: ipcRenderer
    }
);
```

**main.js**

```
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
  });
}
```

**some renderer.js file**

`window.electron.ipcRenderer`

Comment: This is still insecure. Even with a contextBridge, exposing the entirety of the ipcRenderer as a method to the renderer can lead to abuse: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations

Comment: @user1679669 We are exposing a _subset_ of allowed operations on ipcRenderer, which isn't the same as the link you posted. Please see the **new answer** section for a better example of what you can do.

Comment: @reZach
window.api.send is not accessible in vue component onmounted function, how can use it there ?

Answer (score 1):

Notice this sentence in the middle of the [description of context isolation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions). It's easy to miss.

> The Electron API will only be available in the `preload` script and not the loaded page.

Looks like the answer is no.

Comment: Do you know how can the main and renderer processes communicate in this case?

Comment: @amaurymartiny Based on my testing, Node gets totally disabled in the renderer (even if there's no `webview`), and I can't require `ipcRenderer`, so it doesn't look like renderer can talk to main. That being said, it's bit strange that that would be the behavior, since I thought it would only affect the webview/preload and is the reason why I posted [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10405) issue.

Comment: @amaurymartiny [This](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11608#issuecomment-367508850) could help. Looks like Electron APIs are available in the preload and in main. So you should still be able to send messages from preload to main, just not from the webview/preload renderer to the other renderer "wrapping" it

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://github.com/kewde/electron-sandbox-boilerplate/blob/master/sandbox-preload-extended/electron/renderer/preload-extended.js). It works for me. I am using CRA & Electron.

**preload.js**

```js
    const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
    const MESSAGE_TYPES = ipcRenderer.sendSync('GET_MESSAGE_TYPES');
    
    require = null;
    
    class SafeIpcRenderer { ... }
    
    const registerMessages = () => {
      const safeIpcRenderer = new SafeIpcRenderer(Object.values(MESSAGE_TYPES));
    
      contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ELECTRON', {
        sendMessage: safeIpcRenderer.send,
        onReceiveMessage: safeIpcRenderer.on,
        MESSAGE_TYPES,
      });
    };
    
    registerMessages();
```

**main.js**

```js
    const registerPreloadImports = require('./src/client/preloadUtils');
    
    // Required if sandbox flag is set to true. Non-electron modules cannot be directly imported in preload script.
    // For more info please check https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option
    registerPreloadImports();
    
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      // Web preferences for mainWindow
      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/preload.js'),
        contextIsolation: true, // TODO: Remove it once it's enabled by default (from Electron v12)
        disableBlinkFeatures: 'Auxclick',
        sandbox: true,
        // https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option#status
        enableRemoteModule: false,
      },
    });
```

**preloadUtils.js**

```js
    const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
    const MESSAGE_TYPES = require('../utils/messageTypes');
    
    const registerPreloadImports = () => {
      ipcMain.on(MESSAGE_TYPES.GET_MESSAGE_TYPES, (event, message) => {
        event.returnValue = MESSAGE_TYPES;
      });
    };
    
    module.exports = registerPreloadImports;
```

**messageTypes.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      DNS_ONLINE_STATUS: 'dns-online-status',
      APP_ONLINE_STATUS: 'online-status',
      ONLINE_MODEL_SYNC: 'online-model-sync',
      APP_ONLINE: 'app-online',
      INITIAL_DATA_SYNC: 'INITIAL_DATA_SYNC',
      GET_MESSAGE_TYPES: 'GET_MESSAGE_TYPES',
    };
```

**actions.js** (renderer)

```js
    const { MESSAGE_TYPES, sendMessage } = window.ELECTRON || {};
    
    if (!MESSAGE_TYPES) return;
    
    const actions = {
      [MESSAGE_TYPES.INITIAL_DATA_SYNC]: (event, initialSync) => {
        console.log(MESSAGE_TYPES.INITIAL_DATA_SYNC, initialSync);
      },
    
      [MESSAGE_TYPES.ONLINE_MODEL_SYNC]: (event, message) => {
        console.log(MESSAGE_TYPES.ONLINE_MODEL_SYNC, message);
      },
    
      [MESSAGE_TYPES.APP_ONLINE]: (event, isOnline) => {
        console.log(MESSAGE_TYPES.APP_ONLINE, isOnline);
      },
    };
    
    const registerActions = () => {
      const { onReceiveMessage } = window.ELECTRON;
    
      Object.keys(actions).forEach((messageType) => {
        onReceiveMessage(messageType, actions[messageType]);
      });
    };
    
    registerActions();
```

**package.json**

```
    {
      "dependencies": {
        "cross-env": "7.0.2",
        "deepmerge": "4.2.2",
        "electron-is-dev": "1.2.0",
        "electron-log": "4.2.2",
        "electron-updater": "4.3.1",
        "sequelize-cli": "6.2.0",
        "sequelize": "6.3.3",
        "sqlite3": "5.0.0",
        "umzug": "2.3.0",
        "uuid": "8.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "5.2.0",
        "electron": "9.1.0",
        "electron-builder": "22.7.0",
        "spectron": "11.1.0",
        "wait-on": "5.1.0",
        "xvfb-maybe": "0.2.1"
      }
    }
```