# In Electron, how to make ipcRenderer available to multiple renderer processes via global variable defined in preload.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In order to maintain security thanks to `contextIsolation: false` I typically make `ipcRenderer` available to the renderer process by creating a global variable in `preload.js` like this:

```
const electron = require('electron');

process.once('loaded', () => {
  global.ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
});
```

Then, `ipcRenderer` can be directly used in my (primary) renderer process:

```
<script>
...
ipcRenderer.send(...)
...
</script>
```

However, when I am opening a second window (i.e., I am creating a second renderer process), `ipcRenderer` is not defined. Why can't the second renderer process access my global variable? How can I resolve this issue? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you use to open *both* `BrowserWindow`s, the first one as well as the second. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I think, I have found the answer myself (by trying a lot of different approaches). I will put my answer below and would highly appreciate if you could tell me if my answer is correct (or makes sense, at least).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things and I think that I have found a solution. However, I have no idea whether this is the "best practice" way to do it. Any opinion from the community would be highly appreciated.

The second renderer process can access the global variable `ipcRenderer` if it also uses the same `preload.js`. I thought that using `preload.js` again would be somehow redundant or even wrong, but it solves the issue. Here is the code that worked:

```
function openModal() {
  let modalWin = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: win,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  })

  modalWin.loadFile('modal.html');
  modalWin.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    modalWin.show()
  })
}
```

Comment: This is not ideal because it exposes the whole ipcRenderer and disables ContextIsolation. You should be safe if you don't load any remote content at all, however it is still better to use a safer approach, just in case. This answer is more secure since it only exposes needed functions and channels: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59675116/13752696